# I'm query max value it's duplicate values

Tags: sql-server-2008, subquery, max

I want query from sql server 2088 R2. But it's duplicate values​​.

I need it's not duplicate values​​.

Code:

```
Select es.EmpCode,es.Eff,es.Year,MAX(es.Month)
From SP_EffEmpAnalysis es
Where es.Year = '2012'
Group By es.EmpCode,es.Eff,es.Year
Order By es.EmpCode,MAX(es.Month) desc
```

**Output**

```
EmpCode | Eff | Year | Month
1410013 | 0 | 2012 |    11
1450021 | 0.952700018882751 |   2012 |  8
1460037 | 0.653999984264374 |   2012 |  9
1460037 | 0.809899985790253 |   2012 |  8
1460037 | 0.863600015640259 |   2012 |  7
1460047 | 0.796299993991852 |   2012 |  7
1480013 | 0             | 2012 |    11
1480080 | 0.91839998960495 |    2012 |  12
1480080 | 0.982299983501434 |   2012 |  11
1480080 | 1.08259999752045 |    2012 |  10
1480080 | 0.989700019359589 |   2012 |  9
```

**I need ouput**

```
EmpCode | Eff | Year | Month
1410013 | 0 | 2012 |    11
1450021 | 0.952700018882751 |   2012 |  8
1460037 | 0.653999984264374 |   2012 |  9
1460047 | 0.796299993991852 |   2012 |  7
1480013 | 0             | 2012 |    11
1480080 | 0.91839998960495 |    2012 |  12
```

Comment: what is special about EmpCdoe 1450021? Why do you want its Eff  for 2012/8 and not the one of EmpCode 1460037? or do you maybe want their SUM or AVG?

Comment: no sum i want current value by month and year

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the last month's values per employee. You can get that with the row-number function:

```
SELECT EmpCdoe, Eff, Year, Month
FROM(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY EmpCode ORDER BY Year DESC, Month DESC) AS frn
WHERE Year = '2012'
)X
WHERE frn=1
ORDER BY EmpCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sebastian typed faster, but I think this is more complete:

```
select EmpCode, Eff, Year, Month
  from (
    select es.EmpCode, es.Eff, es.Year, es.Month,
      Row_Number() over ( partition by es.EmpCode order by es.Year desc, es.Month desc ) as RN
      from SP_EffEmpAnalysis es
      where es.Year = '2012' ) as Placeholder
  where RN = 1
  order By es.EmpCode
```